# C# I want to select one item through multiple listboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am pretty new in programming and I would like to ask you if I can select 1 item from listbox which will select all items in same line in other listboxes.

Comment: Yes. you can do this with code.

Comment: Provide what you've tried with [mcve], and someone will point the problem.

Comment: Probably you are looking for `DataGridView`. Also if for any reason you want to use `ListBox`, using data-binding if all `ListBox` controls are bound to a single list showing different columns, then the selected index of them will change simultaneously.

Comment: Reza Aghaei thanks for help. As I said I am new to the programming and I have been using stuff that we mostly learnt in the school. You helped me a lot, thanks!